# looking at old build's "what's new" messages

Tags: app-store-connect

I'm looking to give an overview of the changes that have been made to my app. So I thought I could look the old builds and their "what's new" messages in itunes connect but I couldn't find an option like this. Is it somewhere hidden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to look at the old ones? I'm not sure whether that is possible but you could look up your app in the appStore and under 'earlier version' (or something like that) you will see all the change logs you wrote last times.

Comment: that's what I looked for. thanks!
I just need to make a presentation for a funder of the project. and they wanna know what we did with the money.... ;)

Comment: Oh I see, well I'm always glad to help and good luck with your presentation :)